# Text Box Remembers Last Entry

Tags: excel, forms, textbox

Working with Excel 2017, I have created a form that allows my user to seek out a specific work order number and add work details. If a match is found in the appropriate worksheet it then loads the PO#, part number, serial number, and the current status, associated with that record. The problem is that it is also displaying the last entry in the "Add Details" text box. This is not what I had in mind.

Screen shot of the problem

[image: 1]

I initially thought it was pulling the data from column K (11 numerically) for the record in question, but when I plugged in a different work order number into the form and ran the code again, I found the same issue and discovered that the "Begin Work -" annotation didn't exist in that record, I knew something else was amiss.

The form opens with all fields blank so I know the form is starting correctly. And the code looks right (see code below). The specific column that the "Add Details" field updates is the "Details" column on my spreadsheet(ws2). In the code, the text box for "Add Details is Cells(i, 11).Value.

```
ws2.Activate 'Move to Open Worksheet

'***** CHECK FOR DUPLICATE ENTRIES WORK THIS WITH SEARCH CODE*****

Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
iRow = ActiveCell.Row
lastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

InitFind: 'Find Matching Work Order number to Form Input
For i = 3 To lastRow 'SEARCH FOR DUPLICATE WO & PO NUMBERS
    wo = Cells(i, 3).Value
    If WN = wo Then
        po = Cells(i, 4).Value
        pn = Cells(i, 5).Value
        sn = Cells(i, 6).Value
        st = Cells(i, 2).Value
        
        Me.txt_po.Value = po
        Me.txt_pn.Value = pn
        Me.txt_sn.Value = sn
        Me.cmb_Stat.Value = st
        YN = MsgBox("Is this the record that you want?", vbYesNo)
            If YN = vbYes Then
                Me.txt_Detail.Value = ""
                Me.cmb_Stat.SetFocus
                Me.cmd_More.Visible = True
                Me.cmd_CloseWO.Visible = True
                Me.cmd_Update.Visible = True
                Me.cmd_Find.Visible = False
                
                    If Me.txt_pn.Value = "31406-002" Or Me.txt_pn.Value = "31406-003" Then
                        GoTo Batt
                    ElseIf Me.txt_pn.Value = "40-424" Or Me.txt_pn.Value = "40-423" Then
                        GoTo Wheel
                    ElseIf Me.txt_pn.Value = "40-478" Or Me.txt_pn.Value = "40-479" Then
                        GoTo Wheel
                    ElseIf Me.txt_pn.Value = "3-1501" Then
                        GoTo Wheel
                    Else
                        GoTo Update
                    End If
            Else
                Me.txt_WN.Value = ""
                Me.txt_po.Value = ""
                Me.txt_pn.Value = ""
                Me.txt_sn.Value = ""
                Me.cmb_Stat.Value = ""
                Me.txt_Detail.Value = ""
                Me.txt_WN.SetFocus
                Exit Sub
            End If
    End If
Next i

MsgBox "Searched through all open WO's, No match found. Re-enter Work Order number or click Exit."
Me.txt_WN.Value = ""
Me.txt_WN.SetFocus
Exit Sub
```

As you can see the code looks correct. Additionally, I never specifically call for the "Find" code to retrieve the contents of column 11(the details box). So why is it remembering the last entry? The most effective work around I have found thus far was forcing the `Me.txt_Detail.Value = ""` if the user clicks Yes in the message box. While this works, the last entry still shows, and I fear confusion on the part of the end user may occur if I don't find a way to resolve this. I will also note that this particular problem doesn't appear until I click the "Find" button thus initiating the macro.

I've tried resetting the text box in question before the form actually closes and saves all the data (see next lines of code), but even that doesn't work. I saw another post that suggest a pushkey or a SendKey (I think), but even that didn't seem to work. The problem is definitely occuring between lines 6 & 18 of the code above (InitFind - YN), but I can't seem to isolate why.

```
FinishSub:
Me.txt_Detail.Value = ""
ws1.Activate
Unload Me
```

I've also tried relocating the `Me.txt_Details.Value = ""` code to multiple places in the code both before and after the "Find" button is clicked. No matter what I seem to do, once the "Find" button is clicked, the last text entered in the Details box always appears. Note, this happens before the YN message box line.

I reviewed the properties of the text box at length, but can't seem to find anything out of the ordinary. I tried setting the value property of the textbox to "", but all that did was place the quotations in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to waste everyone's time. I found the solution.

I created a subroutine in the module that would enter specific information into the Add Details box when the user changed the status using the combobox (Me.cmb_Stat.Value) as a precursor to additional information in the code above. This subroutine is separate from the Find subroutine, and explains why I couldn't figure this out.

```
Private Sub cmb_Stat_Change()

If Me.cmb_Stat.Value = "Leak Check" Then
    Me.txt_Detail.Value = "Accomplished Wheel build-up, awaiting 24hr leak check and final paperwork. - "
ElseIf Me.cmb_Stat.Value = "In Work" Then
    Me.txt_Detail.Value = "Begin Work - "
ElseIf Me.cmb_Stat.Value = "Parts" Then
    Me.txt_Detail.Value = "Work placed on hold. Waiting for ordered parts/materials - "
End If

End Sub
```

Because I incorrectly set the firing event to the "Change" event, the event fired every time the user clicked "Find." When I changed the event from "Change" to "AfterUpdate", the problem corrected itself. I apologize for posting a question that I found the solution to myself, but I thought it might be helpful to others to post what I found.